# Error installing XMLRPC_C

Tags: ubuntu, curl, xml-rpc

I am trying to install XMLRPC_C in my Ubuntu.

I have installed curl as pre-requisite to the HTML wrapper.

I have checked out stable release of the XMLRPC from sourceforge.

When I run make after ./configure, it exits saying:

> registry.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void xmlrpc_c::method2::execute(const xmlrpc_c::paramList&, xmlrpc_c::value*)’:
>
> registry.cpp:73:20: error: uninitialized const ‘nullCallInfo’ [-fpermissive]
>
> blddir/include/xmlrpc-c/registry.hpp:17:24: note: ‘const class xmlrpc_c::callInfo’ has no >user-provided default constructor
>
> make[2]: *** [registry.o] Error 1
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sridutt/Downloads/xmlrpc-c/src/cpp'
>
> make[1]: *** [cpp/all] Error 2
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sridutt/Downloads/xmlrpc-c/src'
>
> make: *** [src/all] Error 2

When I checked in forums, it gives Fedora RC15 bugfix.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the below steps:

1. Installed libc6, libcurl3, zlib1g
2. Then I installed curl 7.21.6 from the source folders, (sudo-apt could not solve as xmlrpc installation said some types.h missing in newer version of curl)
3. Then followed normal installation from stable release of xmlrpc-c